# How to kill processes spawned in nightwatch globals.js before: function in the after:function

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn, nightwatch.js

I am new to nightwatch and node.js and need help on the following.
I spawn a child process in the before function as part of nightwatch set up and wants to kill the process in before function(teardown). How do i do that. I am not sure of using the x.kill.

```
module.exports = {
    before: function(done) {
        spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
        var x = spawn('./abc');
        done();
    },
    after: function(done) {
        done();
        //how to kill x spawned in before function.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
module.exports = {
    before: function(done) {
        spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
        var x = spawn('./abc');
        process.on('exit', function() {
        x.kill('SIGKILL');}});
        done();
        },
    after: function(done) {
         proces.exit(0);
         done();
    }
}
```